# How Can I Import data from txt/xls files using Cucumber/Capybara?

Tags: ruby, testing, cucumber, capybara, bdd

I'm new to  Cucumber/Capybara, I want to know How Can I Import data from txt/xls files using Cucumber/Capybara

for example I need to use next Scenario to Upload several files one after another :

feature

```
Scenario: Upload
    When I Choose A name "name"
    When I Choose "/home/path"
    Then I Click Upload
```

step_definitions

```
When(/^I Choose A name "([^"]*)"$/) do |title|
  fill_in('video_title', :with => title)
    fill_in('video_description', :with => title)
end

When(/^I Choose "([^"]*)"$/) do |file|
    find(:xpath, '//*[@id="file"]', :visible => false).set(file)
end

Then(/^I Click Upload$/) do
    click_button('Upload')
end
```

so if i can add step definition to import from txt or xls that will be much easier then repeating Scenario for every file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question. To clarify, are you saying that you want to do this same basic thing for several files? If so, here's how I would do it:

Feature:

```
Scenario Outline: Upload
  When I upload a video named "<name>" from path "<path>"

  Examples:
    | name | path         |
    | foo  | /path/1      |
    | bar  | /path/2      |
    | baz  | /path/3      |
```

Steps:

```
When(/^I choose a name "(.*)"$/) do |name|
  fill_in('video_title', :with => name)
  fill_in('video_description', :with => name)
end

When(/^I choose "([^"]*"$/) do |file|
  find(:xpath, '//*[@id="file"]', :visible => false).set(file)
end

When(/^I click "([^"]*"$/ do |button|
  click_button(button)
end

When(/^I upload a video named "[^"]*" from path "[^"]*"$/ do |title, path|
  step 'I choose a name "' + title + '"'
  step 'I choose "' + path + '"'
  step 'I click "Upload"'
end
```

This is assuming you're using the other steps in some other scenario. If you're not, it would make more sense to just define the one step 'I upload a video named "" from path ""'.

If this doesn't answer your question, please let me know what you need different and I'll see if I can help.

Comment: you are close, but i want to import the data from external file ? , and what's the name of the operation you just made ?

Comment: I'll answer your second question first since it's the simplest one. First, I used a scenario outline instead of a regular scenario. That lets you include an arbitrary number of different data points. Next, I used the `step` keyword to call the three step definitions from the fourth one. Both of those are good ways to reduce duplication a bit.

Comment: As for your first question, why do you need to test that many different data points? For most situations, that wouldn't really be necessary, so I'd generally recommend going with a more limited number of examples put into a scenario outline (which can still be arbitrarily long, like I said). If there's some reason that's absolutely not an acceptable option, then I'd create a helper module (keep it in your `features/support` directory) that would extract the data from a file & process it using regular Ruby. You can then call that helper code from your steps.

Comment: The thing about Cucumber is, it's an opinionated tool. If something in Cucumber seems too hard, it's likely to be because you're going about it in the wrong way.